# Gem list - empty gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

hi im having difficulity with my machine

when i ask for my gem list

```
gem list
```

it dosent show my gems but when i put sudo on it, it shows

```
sudo gem list
```

also when im trying to make a new project like

```
rails new <project-name>
```

it comes with this error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

uhm latelty my machine was ok i guess i just got in to this when i install rvm and change my ruby versio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet somehow because of how you installed your gems, they were installed at the user level, for the root user.

You can probably just install then for your own user with `gem install rails`.

The tools [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build), and [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) are a big help in keeping sane and organized when using various gems in various projects.

Comment: uhm latelty my machine was ok i guess i just got in to this when i install rvm and change my ruby version